# Ubuntu 20/18 & Windows10 dual boot with AMD & NVIDIA cards - stuck at boot screen and not finding drivers

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, windows, amd-ryzen

I've recently bought the [ROG Flow X13](https://rog.asus.com/laptops/rog-series/2021-rog-flow-x13-series/spec), which has the AMD Ryzen™ 9 5900HS  and NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 with Max-Q, and comes with Win10 pre-installed. I followed usual Ubuntu dual-boot installation tutorials with Ubuntu 20.04 iso on Rufus-loaded USB, enabled install 3rd party drives, and the installation seemed to be going fine. When prompted to restart, it now shows the Grub as it should, but when selecting Ubuntu as OS it only loads the ROG splash screen and then gets stuck.

I tried the following common suggestions but none worked:

1. edit the Ubuntu startup commands: add nomodeset (didn't work), or add nouveau.noaccel=1 (didn't work), or replace quiet splash with noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll (didn't work)
2. in recovery mode, repair packages, it did install quite a lot (things like java, libreoffice, thunderbird...) but didn't change anything when trying to start up
3. in recovery mode -> root, uncomment #Wayland = false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, reboot -> still stuck at splash screen

I opened journalctl --since today in the root terminal, I am not sure what to look for but some remarks that might or might not be useful:

AMD related:

- `[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting`
- `AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported`, followed by `can't derive routing for PCI INT A` `PCI INT A: not connected`
- `Direct firmare load for amdgpu/green_sardine_gpu_info failed with error -2` `Failed to load gpu_info firmware amdgpu/green_sardine_gpu_info` `Fatal error during GPU init` `[drm] amdgpu: finishing device` `BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference: address: (...)`,`#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode`, `#PF: error_code (0x0000) - not-present page`

I also found hat the nvidia card specs were printed out correctly by the gdm-x-session logger, so it does seem to find it generally.

I did manage to enter Ubuntu at some point in an earlier attempt to install (I have freshly installed it since so I can write this question more clearly knowing what i did/n't do), though it was after numerous hours of randomly trying different commands I don't remember anymore, and I remember it was still not detecting the NVIDIA GPU at all (in nvidia-settings) and had difficulties with AMD, too. So I assume this must be the tough combination of AMD + NVIDIA?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the latest Ubuntu version(currently 21.04) and latest kernel available for the newer laptop such as x13 flow.

You shoud manually add green sardine firmware(for AMD cezanne internal GPU) to /lib/firmware/amdgpu if it does not exist there.

Comment: Thanks! Ubuntu 21.04. is working:)